# how to create table with unique rows out of two tables

Tags: mysql

i have two tables, with same columns. but there are duplicates. i want to create third one but without duplicate rows. what is the best way to do this keeping in mind that tables have over million records? 
Table have two columns, ean and price

Comment: `duplicates` as in _duplicate key_ or as in _all but one can be dropped_ (select distinct…from…union…)?

Answer (score 0):

If both the tables have same structure then , I think you should try union.

Sample Query--
Assuming 2 table from which the data needs to be retrieved as
table_src_1
table_src_2

Final Table-table_unique_records

Your Query-
create table table_unique_records as 
(select * from table_src_1
union 
select * from table_src_2)